# AG-Grid: rows that are selected and disabled are showing as selectable in getSelectedNodes()

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Following the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/#example-forcing-checkboxes-as-selected) to render a row selected and disabled works great. When calling [getSelectedNodes()](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/#reference-selection-getSelectedNodes) I was expecting those nodes that are disabled to show as `selectable: false` but it is still returning `selectable: true`.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Would be nice to filter on selectable and get only those selected by the user.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.